# DatePicker Flyout Presenter Style

Tags: xaml, datepicker, styles, uwp

I'm looking for a way to edit the DatePickerFlyoutPresenter scroll box style. I want to change the text to white the arrow buttons and change the pointover colors but cant seem to find it. could it be useing flipview style? I am using xaml/C#

http://puu.sh/lKvcW/a921089600.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **Live Visual Tree** of Visual Studio, we can find `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter` use `LoopingSelector` in it.

[image]

So to change the color of the text in arrow button, we can change the template of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector`, and we can find it in  **generic.xaml** which typical in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic

OR

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic

This location depends on the Windows 10 SDK you've installed.

The default style for `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector` is following:

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelector -->
<Style TargetType="LoopingSelector">
    <Setter Property="ShouldLoop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrimaryText}" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="15" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UpButton"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DownButton"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" />
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="UpButton" Content="&#xE70E;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="8" Height="16" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}" IsTabStop="False" />
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="DownButton" Content="&#xE70D;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="8" Height="16" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}" IsTabStop="False" />
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To change the text to white, we can add `Foreground="White"` in `RepeatButton` like:

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="UpButton" Foreground="White" Content="&#xE70E;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="8" Height="16" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}" IsTabStop="False" />
<RepeatButton x:Name="DownButton" Foreground="White" Content="&#xE70D;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="8" Height="16" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}" IsTabStop="False" />
```

Changing the pointer over colors is similar. We can change the template of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelectorItem`:

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingSelectorItem -->
<Style TargetType="LoopingSelectorItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="LoopingSelectorItem">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent" >
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected" >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Margin="2,0,2,0" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this template, we can change the `Background` in the `VisualState` named `PointerOver` to customize the pointer over color.

Comment: I'm a bit new to using the live visual tree and tried that to see what it was but I'm guessing I needed to click on the datepicker to see the datepickerpresenter to find this. LoopingSelector is what I needed. just didn't know what it was called and this worked.

Comment: All of this worked correctly except the Year LoopingSelector has a small gap between each item. I think it is because the year does not loop. have a look
http://puu.sh/lMJ8c/8f8b229f4f.png

Comment: Is there something similar for WinPhone 8.1 versus UWP?  I don't see anything similar in generic.xaml or themeresources.xaml, but it's possible I missed the needle in those haystacks.